# Need understanding on how to get/display User Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I’m in the process of learning MVC with Identity 2 and I’m at the point of taking a sample project and tweaking it to fit a site that I’m trying to convert from WebForms with ASP.Net Membership provider.

What I’m having issues with at the moment is getting my head wrapped around how I get a value from another table to populate a property in a class.

I have a class called AppUser.cs and it inherits from IdentityUser. That is basically mapped to a table named “AspNetUsers” using EntityFramework. I’ve added a couple more properties (First/Last Name) to that table using EF migrations. Now I want to display what Role the user is assigned to and eventually will need to get a list of the available roles and add them to a dropdownlist. I added the RoleName property to my AppUser class but I’m assuming that since that data is not stored in the AspNetUsers table is why I’m getting an error “Invalid column name 'RoleName'”.

How would I populate the Role and/or get a list of available Roles in my AppUser class so I can display it in my View?

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
    }
```

The model on the view “Index.cshtml” is the AppUser.

```
@model IEnumerable<AppUser>
```

This is my ActionResult for my Controller.

```
   public ActionResult Index() {
                return View(UserManager.Users);
            }

private AppUserManager UserManager {
            get {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
            }
        }
```

This is the AppUserManager.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using SampleMvcSite.Models;

namespace SampleMvcSite.Infrastructure {
    public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser> {

        public AppUserManager(IUserStore<AppUser> store)
            : base(store) {
        }

        public static AppUserManager Create(
                IdentityFactoryOptions<AppUserManager> options,
                IOwinContext context) {

            AppIdentityDbContext db = context.Get<AppIdentityDbContext>();
            AppUserManager manager = new AppUserManager(new UserStore<AppUser>(db));

            manager.PasswordValidator = new CustomPasswordValidator {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
                RequireDigit = false,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true
            };

            manager.UserValidator = new CustomUserValidator(manager) {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            return manager;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED CODE:**
I ended up creating a class called UserEditViewModel and I'm also including the AppRole class which was in the sample project I'm tweaking.

```
   public class UserEditViewModel : IdentityUser
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string UserRole { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<AppRole> AllRoles { get; set; }
        }

    public class AppRole : IdentityRole {

        public AppRole() : base() { }

        public AppRole(string name) : base(name) { }
    }
```

Then in my controller I did the following. Keep in mind I'm only going to allow a user to be assigned to one role at a time so theoretically there should only be the one role which is why I only called on the userRoles[0]. Since I added the RoleManager after some sample users I have a couple users that aren't assigned to a Role. I added a check to make sure the Roles had a count and if not I display "User" as their role. I will go back and add code to actually add the user to the "User" role if no roles are found.

```
List<UserEditViewModel> UserList = new List<UserEditViewModel>();

            var users = UserManager.Users;
            foreach (AppUser user in users)
            {                    
                var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
                string roleName = userRoles.Count() == 0 ? "User" : userRoles[0];

                UserEditViewModel editUser = new UserEditViewModel();
                editUser.UserName = user.UserName;
                editUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                editUser.LastName = user.LastName;
                editUser.Email = user.Email;
                editUser.UserRole = roleName;
                editUser.AllRoles = RoleManager.Roles;
                UserList.Add(editUser);
            }

            return View(UserList);
```

Here is the View

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Role:</label> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserRole)
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with RoleManager? There's a relationship b/w Users and Roles, you can use that. Your view should have another model that contains what is needs, maybe Appuser and a string Rolename for instance.

Comment: I don't know enough about RoleManager. I'll look it up and see if I can implement it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at ViewModels. It's generally bad practice to update an entity model in your view - especially security related entities. See https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/03/Why-You-Never-Expose-Your-Domain-Model-As-Your-MVC-Model/

With a viewmodel, you could have a property for `List<Role>` that you populate in your controller and use in your view and another property like RoleId for the user's role.

In the POST you would do something like:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{ 
    var roleMgr = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
    var userMgr = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
    var role = roleMgr.FindById(viewmodel.RoleId);
    if (role != null) userMgr.AddToRole(viewmodel.UserId, role.Name);
}
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleId)
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, Model.RoleList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. I've read about ViewModels and I'm going to try to implement one. Question: in my Index ActionResult on the controller it's currently just returning the UserManger.Users straight to the View(). If I make a class called UserEditViewModel with the properties I need then I assume I should just take that list of users from the UserManger.Users, loop through them, and add populated UserEditViewModel objects to another list that I would then pass to the View.cshtml?

Comment: Wish I knew how to add my updated code but I used a ViewModel in my Index. I'm looping through the user list, creating new VM objects, and adding them to another list that I pass as model to my View. That works and I'm assuming that's the best way to do that. However, I created an string property called UserRole in the ViewModel. I'm trying to set that property by returning the first value of the list of roles.

Comment: In the debugger I can see the [0] position of the userRoles list = "User". I'm trying to assign that value to my editUser.UserRole = userRoles[0] but nothing is getting set. How can I assign the value of the first item? I keep getting an error "Index was out of range."

Comment: OK, to build the ViewModel for the index or display, you just need to use the role manager to look up your RoleId and assign the name. For Create and Update you would build a list of roles and bind it to your RoleId as shown in edit. Let me know if you have a followup question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I only get a little time to work on this because it's a side project but I was finally able to get the RoleName. The ViewModel is the way to go and that is making more sense to me now. The issue I was having with getting the role name is that I added the RoleManager after I had added some sample users so there were some users without any roles at all. Once I put a check for that it worked. I updated my code above and will work on the DropDownList next.