# ASP.Net Identity .FindIdAsync not finding user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I’m still working on trying to get a sample app with Identity 2 working. In the following post I got help adding role information to a ViewModel to display my users. 
[Need understanding on how to get/display User Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239337/need-understanding-on-how-to-get-display-user-role)

Now I’m trying to address an issue I have when I click on the Edit button of the user. My controller keeps coming up NULL for the user when I try finding it with the .FindIdAsync method. However, in debug mode I can see the correct ID being passed into the Edit ActionResult.

Would the fact that I’m using a ViewModel in my Index View have anything to do with it? I would have thought that since the ID is being passed correctly that the ViewModel would be out of the picture at that point.

I’ve searched over the web but can’t find anything to help me figure out the problem.

This is the ActionResult and in debug I can see the id being populated with the correct value. So, I have no idea why it’s not finding the record. There are no error messages, it's just returning a NULL for the user object which is displaying the "User Not Found" error on every user I have in my table.

I'm hoping someone can help point me at something I can look at to help figure this one out.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string id)
{
    AppUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user != null)
    {
        return View(user);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error", new string[] { "User Not Found" });
    }
}

public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

This is the ViewModel I’m using on the Index View which I wouldn’t think would have anything to do with this issue but showing it just in case.

```
public class UserEditVM : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserRole { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AppRole> AllRoles { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my AppUserManager

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser>
{
    public AppUserManager(IUserStore<AppUser> store)
        : base(store) 
    {
    }

    public static AppUserManager Create(
            IdentityFactoryOptions<AppUserManager> options,
            IOwinContext context) 
    {

        AppIdentityDbContext db = context.Get<AppIdentityDbContext>();
        AppUserManager manager = new AppUserManager(new UserStore<AppUser>(db));

        manager.PasswordValidator = new CustomPasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true
        };

        manager.UserValidator = new CustomUserValidator(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        return manager;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** here is my updated ViewModel. Removed inheritance and added the properties I needed from IdentityUser.

```
public class UserEditVM 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserRole { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AppRole> AllRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your view model really shouldn't inherit from IdentityUser, you could end up subjecting yourself to an overposting attack.  You should have an object that you map your values to that is purely for the use of the view and contains only the fields required for display on the view.  I doubt you need to display the PasswordHash on the view right?

Comment: Are you definitely connected to the correct database, if you add a new user to the database on the line before using your user manager, is it added to the correct database?

Comment: Good call on removing the inheritance of IdentityUser. Once I did that it seems to have worked. I don't really understand why though because theoretically the properties would all be available to my ViewModel class...albeit with a lot of extra properties that I didn't really need. I updated to show the new view model.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, if you just use the existing Identity Model and implement a class like below which inherits Interfaces like `IUserStore<User>, IUserLoginStore<User>` You might be able to handle any Async methods yourselves.

Example: refer code below, btw this code uses [dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), so you might use your own ORM:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserLoginStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>, IUserRoleStore<User>
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public UserStore()
    {
        this.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    }      

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns User tables information, based on parameter type userId/Username will be equated in where condition
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userId">userId or Username can be passed</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId.ToString()))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userId", string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid format.", new { userId }));

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@userId", userId);

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                return connection.Query<User>("spUsers_GetUser", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
        });
    }
```

}